# Compute sum Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have made a custom module budget with the field Value. I would like to sum all the values for the budgets I've made today

```
    def value_budget_day(self):
    for budget in self:
        # Encontrar si hoy es el mismo dia que se creo un presupuesto
        c_date = datetime.strftime(budget.create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        t_date = datetime.strftime(budget.today, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        create_day = c_date[:10]
        today_day = t_date[:10]

        if create_day == today_day:
            # Sumar todos los valores de los presupuestos de ese día
           total = 0.0
           for val in budget:
               total += val.value
           budget.today_value = total

        else:
            budget.today_value = 35
```

In my code the values are not sum

[image]

Comment: can you put a screenshot we may understand what you want exactly!

Comment: https://paste.pics/62e62cf057c9e03d604693415d6b3f30 I would like to do this logic, then i will use the todaybudgetvalue in a kanban view

Answer (score 0):

```
def value_budget_day(self):
    total = 0
    for budget in self:
        # Encontrar si hoy es el mismo dia que se creo un presupuesto
        c_date = datetime.strftime(budget.create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        t_date = datetime.strftime(budget.today, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        create_day = c_date[:10]
        today_day = t_date[:10]

        if create_day == today_day:
            # Sumar todos los valores de los presupuestos de ese día
            total += budget.value
            budget.today_value = total

        else:
            budget.today_value = 0

today_value = fields.Float(compute='value_budget_day')
```